# Sencha Touch app packaged with Cordova blank on Device, first launch

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch

I have a Sencha Touch app that runs fine on both desktop and mobile browsers. However, when I build it to a native Android app using Cordova, on the very first launch of the application, the splash screen displays and after that the screen is blank. If I close and reopen the app, the splash screen displays and the main menu appears after, and the app works fine.

Any ideas what could be causing such behaviour?

Comment: First time whether it takes long tym to load ? or its not loading at all ?

Comment: Doesn't load past the splash screen on the first launch after a fresh install. Could it be something like the stores not being ready in time or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a logging tool like http://jsconsole.com/ to see if something went wrong.

Also, you can try to add this script into your index.html to alert all script errors:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // output errors to console log
    if ('true' === 'true') {
        window.onerror = function (message, filename, lineno, colno, error) {
            alert("window.onerror ::" + message + " in " + filename + " at " + lineno);
            if (error != null) {
                alert(error.stack);
            }
        };
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! It definitely seems like Ext.stores are not being loaded until I close and reopen the app. So on first launch, any method that gets from a model gives "undefined is not an object". This happens even though the stores are set to autoLoad: true